# IntelliJ not creating failed.xml File, after running test in TestNG

Tags: xml, selenium, intellij-idea, testng

Supposedly, TestNG creates `failed.xml` file under `test-output->failed.xml`  but in my cases, the file is there but it's NOT showing correct failed test cases( correct XML test cases), It shows test cases that I had run sometime back.

Please suggest what configuration I am missing so it can generate a `failed.xml` file every time I run my test cases.

Comment: Why to tag _Selenium_?

Comment: Will it recreate failed.xml is you remove it before execution? Do you use any build tool (Maven/Gradle)?

Comment: no i did not remove it. I am using maven

Comment: @DebanjanB because my project is based on Testng/Selenium/Maven

Comment: Does it work fine if you run tests outside IDE using maven goals?

Answer (score 0):

In your Run Configuration please check if you have disabled the default listeners. They need to be enabled.

Right click on your XML file
Run Configuration
Scroll down and click on the Listeners tab
Check Use default reporters